# unable to connect to GCM cloud connection server

Tags: google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the example on [this website](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#smack) to implement a GCM server using CCS. However the code has exception when it tries to connect to the gcm server (last line in the code below):

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
    config.setSendPresence(false);
    config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
```

I looked up online and someone said I needed to enable billing for my app on appengine in order to use GCM server. I did so but it still does not work. I keep seeing the following error:

> gcm.googleapis.com:5235 Exception: Permission denied: Attempt to
>   access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)

Am I missing something?